# Error: Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, macos, url, path, directory

I'm having trouble converting URL to string. The **getScreenShotDirectory()** path is `file:///Users/Pat/Desktop/`.

My goal is to convert it to String, so the path can look like `/Users/Pat/Desktop/`

```
let urlString = getScreenShotDirectory()
let pathURL = URL(string: getScreenShotDirectory())!       // error
```

I would gladly provide more code if needed.

Comment: Your description is really confusing. Is `urlString` supposed to be a URL or a path? And what exactly does `getScreenShotDirectory()` return?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that your `getScreenShotDirectory()` method is already a `URL`. So you get the error trying to pass a `URL` to the `URL(string:)` method which, of course, expects a `String`, not a `URL`.

The simple solution is to properly convert the `URL` to a path string:

```
let pathURL = getScreenShotDirectory() // URL
let pathString = pathURL.path // String
```

Comment: Thank You! This fixes my problem (: @rmaddy

Comment: Nice. it is good to have default method without having to use error catching with try!